# endpoints group by resources swagger annotation?

Tags: spring, rest, api, swagger, springfox

I'm using Spring for my REST API development. And I have some API where there are lots of endpoints. When I open up swagger ui, it looks to packed.

I just read [this](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/) article and saw that we can group endpoints based on resource level.

I just want to know how that can be achieved with swagger annotations with Spring. I appreciate if someone can describe with an example.

And also I just wonder whether we can regroup (higher level grouping) the groups we have deduces in above way?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

********** **SOLUTION 1: (using groups)** **********

Just define multiple `Docket` bean for each group, and u will get logical grouping as per your need.

```
@Bean
public Docket api1() {

return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .groupName("users")
    .select()
    .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/users/**"))
    .build();
}

@Bean
public Docket api2() {

return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .groupName("products")
    .select()
    .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/products/**"))
    .build();
}
```

Now you will get two groups in your swagger ui like below.

[image: groups]

********** **SOLUTION 2: (using tags)** **********

You don't need to define multiple `Docket` bean just one is enough.

```
@Bean
public Docket api1() {

// here tags is optional, it just adds a description in the UI
// by default description is class name, so if you use same tag using 
// `@Api` on different classes it will pick one of the class name as 
// description, so better define your own description for them
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .tags(new Tag("users", "users related"), 
          new Tag("products", "products related"))
    .select()
    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.github"))
    .build();
}
```

After that you just need to annotate your api methods with `@Api` (at class level, default for all methods) or `@ApiOperation` (at method level, will override value at class level).

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/products")
@Api(tags = "products")
public class ProductController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "", tags = "products")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Product createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {

        return product;
    }
}
```

[image: tags]

Tags in `@ApiOperation` (or in `@Api`) will work across controller as well, i.e. method in different controller classes (or controller itself) tagged with a given tag will be grouped together.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Upodated the answer with using tags

Comment: Second one is much better. Being able to achieve it without multiple docket definitions is a big win. Thank You for your effort. Hope you also got something out of it too. :))

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'Api' : after i added this line before my method... it said: