# Endpoint grouping/collection using Iris + Swag

Tags: go, swagger-ui, openapi, iris-go

How can I group the endpoints by **Party** ? Which declaration/annotation comment should I use ? I'm having this:

[image]

I need the endpoints to be grouped by something like "Books", "Catalogs" and so on,... not one unique unnamed "default" group. How can I achieve that?

PS: My problem is similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567317/endpoints-group-by-resources-swagger-annotation), but I'm using Iris-Go, and [this](https://github.com/iris-contrib/swagger/tree/v12) plug-in.

**UPDATE1**

.json [file](https://github.com/dani-fmena/go.api.backend/blob/master/docs/swagger.json)

Comment: Please paste your `doc.json` file.

Comment: @Shiv I posted my .json file link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iris-go uses gin-swagger/swaggo under the hood. In Swagger to get endpoints grouped it should be enough to add *tags* (see https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/).

In swaggo you need to use `@Tags` [declarative parameter](https://swaggo.github.io/swaggo.io/declarative_comments_format/api_operation.html#api-operation) in endpoint comment like this:

```golang
// @Tags: Books
```

See swaggo example code with `@Tags` [here](https://github.com/swaggo/swag/blob/master/example/celler/controller/accounts.go).

Comment: Thanks blami but I do have @Tags in my code, and there is no grouping though.

https://github.com/dani-fmena/go.api.backend/blob/master/api/endpoints/Books.go

Comment: It is `@Tags` (even if its just one tag) and not `@Tag` as you have it in your code.

Comment: Blami you’re totally right. Now you pointed out I notice my mistake. I don’t read the spec carefully (I would like to think I was too tired ) I'm going to cross-reference the issue I posted on the iris-contrib/swagger repo to your solution. Thanks again.